# Trying to reinstall without losing data

Tags: boot, login, reinstall

I got stuck in a login loop and followed a few threads advice trying everything to no avail. I tried to create a new account and login that way but it was still stuck in the loop. I tried renaming Xauthority. I eventually ended up trying to reinstall lightdm and ended up with a computer that boots the bios and then the screen goes black.

I did some googling and found that I could reinstall Ubuntu without losing data. But when I made my boot disk and went to install it did not detect the OS and so my only options are to wipe and install or something else.  When I go to something else it has a few devices, I'm not sure what one I should write the OS to so I wont lose my data. I have not been good about backing up everything and have quite a bit of data that would be lost with a wipe and since I can't get into my account I can't see any way of backing up my data. Is there a way to install Ubuntu again without losing all my data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a live CD (or other live media like usb) to get into Ubuntu (try it out mode).  Once there, you can mount all of your partitions which have data you want, and then copy your data to external media (like an external usb disk).  Or if you have unallocated space on your hard drive, you could even use it -- see Advanced: below.

If you need to, you can use "sudo" to get around any permission problems.  There is no password for sudo on the live CD, just use carriage return.

Once you have your data backed up, you can proceed to install Ubuntu.

Advanced:

In the live CD environment, you can inspect all of your devices and figure out where your data is.  In this way, you can answer your questions about which devices or partitions you may want to preserve or use or delete in your new installation.

Or if you have unallocated space, you could even create a new partition on your hard drive using the live CD, and put your data there.

The installer doesn't need the whole disk -- it just needs enough unallocated space and enough primary partition slots, plus (perhaps) some space in the first part of the disk.  So, if you have plenty of space, you could have a logical partition in the last part of the disk (where you could backup your data), and the installer would still proceed. It won't actually modify your disk without warning you, and you can inspect what it is going to do, and modify it a bit, before proceeding.

A favorite tool for me is "parted", to inspect partitions and make partitions.

While you are running the live CD, you can even install packages.  They will persist until you reboot.  So, if your favorite partitioning tool isn't available, you can install it in the live environment.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed. I will give this a try I the morning and update.